# Как распарсить такой json?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Нужно распарсить такой json, как это сделать?

```
{"code":200,"lang":"en-ru","text":["привет"]}
```

P.S Проблема в том, что не могу вытащить значения "text".

То, что я написал:

```
    try {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
        JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("text");
        JSONObject two = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
        Toast.makeText(service.this, two.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Что на выходе: `["привет"]`

Как вытащить этот 0-ой массив?

Comment: Вы серьезно думаете, что вы - первый человек, который парсит JSON на Java?

Comment: `jArray.getString(0);` пробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо, вот прям буквально только что доперло и вы написали :D

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решён. (Спасибо eugeneek)

```
try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("text");
            String getget = jArray.getString(0);
            Toast.makeText(service.this, getget, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```